# Finding indexes of a specific repeated number in array

Tags: python, python-2.7, indexing, duplicates

I am trying to get the index of some repeated elements in an array. Here is the code:

```
cc = []

ang=[12,13,89.0,14,15,16,89.0,17]

class Index:

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.Angle = kwargs['Angle']

    def ind(self):

        for mm in range(0, len(self.Angle)):

            if self.Angle[mm] == 89.0:
                ee = self.Angle.index(self.Angle[mm])
                cc.append(ee)
        return cc

plus = Index(Angle=ang)
plus1 = plus.ind()

print (plus1)
```

I want to find the index of the **repeated number = 89.0** in the list (ang). I am expecting to get [2,6] **but I keep getting [2,2] which is wrong**. Does anybody know how I can fix it? I know it may be possible to do it by changing the format of this code but I prefer to keep this format (using kwargs and class). Thanks!

Comment: Just use `[i for i, e in enumerate(ang) if e == 89.0]`

Comment: I like the `enumerate` over my suggestion below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `list.index(<element>)` returns the index of the element. If the element appears more than once `index()` always returns index of the first occurrence.

However, in your code you don't need to call `index` since you are accessing the element via `mm` that is already the index. Why not just append `mm`. Like:

```
if self.Angle[mm] == 89.0:
    cc.append(mm)
```

Moreover, same code can be elegantly written with list comprehension like:

```
indexes = [x for x in range(0, len(self.Angle)) if self.Angle[x] == 89.0]
```